# Is it possible to acquire/activate subtle physical traits of different races through fluid exchange?

Tags: dermatology, sex, hair, deodorant

I'm male and have always dated different races than my own (Asian). I've noticed that when I started dating a blonde Irish girl, I suddenly developed some blonde facial hair (let's say one in 7 strands of hair, so it's quite noticeable). Keep in mind that up until this point, I (obviously) have only had dark black facial hair on my chin. ***Is this normal? How does one suddenly grow blonde facial hair?*** As far as I'm aware, my lineage is pretty exclusively Asian.

Also, I've been dating this African American girl, and I've noticed that since swapping body fluids (won't go into more details unless necessary), my body's smell has drastically changed (my armpit suddenly smells a little like her lady parts, which is also a distinct smell). It's quite noticeable because of the sudden change in odor. I haven't changed anything about my diet nor other things that would really impact my chemical balance. ***How is this even possible***?

Again, it's not like I go out and modify any noticeably different behaviors in my normal life. But I have noticed the very coincidental correlations that happen when dating.

So, can one acquire other people's chemical traits by swapping fluids somehow?

Or is it like... somehow I'm activating certain traits that I always had dormant?

Comment: I'm upvoting this as an interesting question just as soon as I stop laughing.

Comment: Blond facial hair? Are you absolutely positive it's not gray?

Comment: @Lucky i examined all 25632648 pieces of hair (with a nanoscope) and counted 3661806.6 of them to be blonde.